# How to know when menu is "open" using ECSlidingViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ecslidingviewcontroller

I am using the ecsliding for a menu in my app. I was wondering how to know when the menu is open and when it has control. I am trying to do themes in the menu and am having issues because I "reset" the colours on viewdidload and viewdidappear (for the main "top" view controller").

Essentially :

User opens menu, selects colour, closes menu and colours should change... but since the rightviewcontroller is not actually being fully "added" I don't think the viewdidload and viewdidappear methods get called when I close the menu...

Sorry for the rambling...

Any help?

Thanks

Andy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the docs you should be able to interrogate the [currentTopViewPosition](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/ECSlidingViewController/2.0.1/Classes/ECSlidingViewController.html#//api/name/currentTopViewPosition) property.

This is defined as

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, ECSlidingViewControllerTopViewPosition) {
    /** The top view is on anchored to the left */
    ECSlidingViewControllerTopViewPositionAnchoredLeft,
    /** The top view is on anchored to the right */
    ECSlidingViewControllerTopViewPositionAnchoredRight,
    /** The top view is centered */
    ECSlidingViewControllerTopViewPositionCentered
};
```

It looks like you can access the instance of `ECSlidingViewController` that contains your view controller using  the [UIViewController(ECSlidingViewController)](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/ECSlidingViewController/2.0.1/Categories/UIViewController+ECSlidingViewController.html#//api/name/slidingViewController)`category method`slidingViewController`

Comment: Now would I do this in my topviewcontroller class?

Comment: Okay I will  try this - appreciate it

Comment: I am confused on how to use this to my advantage... I want to know if the top view is anchored this is good...but how do I make a method in my topview controller to constantly look for this? Or how do I message the top view that the menu has just been closed?

Comment: @asavu please post exactly what you figured out for others, thanks.

Comment: How would I go about doing that ? In a new post or a comment or what? I would like to share what I learned from this. Thanks

Comment: Hi, what is the method that its being called when the menu is open? Thanks